# Log4j synchronous I want to catch log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed

Tags: java, log4j

I want to send log info, to a "audit" file. I have thought about using log4j with an exclusive Appender:

```
LOGGER_AUDIT.info("Text of audit");
```

I want to be sure that it is written synchronously. If an exception occurs, such as this:

```
og4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:audit.log (Access denied)
...
```

I want to capture it and stop the execution.

It would be something like this:

```
try {
   LOGGER_AUDIT.info("Text of audit");
} catch(LoggerException logExc) {
   // TODO Ops... the logger do not write.
   throw logExc;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific What do you mean - Exceptions are taken care for in catch blocks? PS: Your english seems fine.

Comment: Hm, I think "synchronously" is not your problem here. What happens, when above message appears? Does the App crash? Of course you can avoid above error by providing a valid writeable path. Log4j(2) will configure itself automatically on first log-call. You could make one at the very start of your app and wrap it in try/catch. If any exception during configuration happens, you should be able to catch it there, if at all.

Comment: Matthias: I edit my comment to add a pseudo-sample :)

Comment: Fildor: I want the App crash if the logger fail.

Comment: Well, I guess wrapping every log-call int try/catch will severely impact performance. Secondly, I am not sure if there actually is a "LoggerException" ... at least I am not aware of it. AFAIK log4j handles Exceptions internally most of the time. I only had NPEs when I was logging some variables (that were null) and wasn't cautious enough once. But that was actually thrown before entering log4j code ...

Comment: To cover the example, you could check specifically if that path can be written to before starting into any business-logic. Usually, you do not want to have log-calls crash your app ... so I guess it will be somewhat tedious to make it do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force log4j configuration processing by calling:

```
BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration();
DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch( log4jConfigPath );
```

To catch the exception you can use ErrorHandler functionality. 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/ErrorHandler.html

This is how it can be configured:

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.varia.FallbackErrorHandler">
       <root-ref/>
       <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  </errorHandler>
  <param name="File" value="C:/temp/test.log"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %30.30c - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

You can put your own ErrorHandler instead of FallbackErrorHandler. By default OnlyOnceErrorHandler is used. It prints the exception to STDERR.

Comment: My custom ErrorHandler, can stop the execution? is it synchronous?

Comment: @vakya, yes, it's syncronous.
btw: you can always dig into log4j code.

Comment: @vakya, check FileAppender#activateOptions() method. it uses errorHandler provided in configuration. Be aware, if you simply throw an exception into error handler it will be caught in DOMConfigurator#parseAppender() method and only InterruptedException or InterruptedIOException lead to thread interruption. If you simply want to shutdown the app, call System.exit()